# How to get Excel to interact with .NET or PowerShell or OData

Tags: excel, powershell, excel-2010, odata

I have a few thousand rows of history data that I want Excel to access.  This data will be used in creating a summary report, sparklines, and a table data.

My question is how should I go about adding new rows to the datasource?  Powershell is required to extract data from the source (Exchange Server)... but then how do I surface that extracted data to Excel2010?

Here are my ideas:

1) Powershell can run externally and save the data to the XLSX (as long as the spreadsheet is closed) using Open XML libraries

2) Use Excel vb macros to call COM via interop (C# object) to get the data from Powershell.  The returned values go to the XLSX (Ugly)

3) ????

(Advanced, not sure if this idea will work with above mentioned features)

If I were to move these rows to an external sheet, or SQL table, then I'd rather use other ways of importing the data into excel.  I dont' know if this will work with sparklines, or tables.  Perhaps I could use OData since it appears to be the most lightweight and firewall friendly.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the external data in SQL Server, Access or another Excel file, it's trivial to access it using Data>Connections.  The data will automatically be formatted as an Excel table with all of Excel's features available.

Comment: The data isn't stored anywhere yet.. it will be created new over time and I'm expecting peak usage to have a few thousand rows.  It's the concept of adding a new row I don't know.  How would this be initated by Excel?

Comment: I was focusing on part 3, and saying that if you "were to move these rows to an external sheet, or SQL table" it would be easy to access the data from Excel.  It sounds like you are also asking how to add data to your source from Excel?  Sorry, I'm confused.

Comment: I haven't yet chosen if the data will be collected and saved ad-hoc or on a routine interval.  If the ad-hoc method is chosen, I think it would be initated from excel.  I think I'm confused and you have a framework (or just program structure).... how would you imagine the SQL beinig updated?  Adhoc or by a timed collection service?

Comment: I don't have a framework.  I'm not even clear on your requirements.  If we're talking PowerShell or Exchange, I'm definitely useless to you.  I don't understand whether or not the data has to come from Exchange initially.  It would also be good to know if you are the only user, what type of data your talking about and any other details that might help focus this question.  Sorry, but I'm floundering here.

Comment: The XLS will be used by 3 people on a weekly basis.  I suppose I just need to lean if Excel can invoke a .NET object (or Powershell)